# Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm comparison

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

I have been studying for my exams when I came across with this problem, guys help please

> For any alignment of pattern P and text T, suppose a mismatch occurs
>   at P[i+1] and T[k] during the execution of KMP algorithm How many
>   times does T[k] come into comparison in total during the execution of
>   KMP algorithm (SPi is non-optimized)

the possible solutions I came across with are

> 1. i-SPi
> 2. SPi+1
> 3. n-i
> 4. n-SPi

but all of them fail on some scenarios,

Comment: @SaadAbdullah , SSMA please only post in English as this is an international community

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev can you help me with this question?
If you need more information please ask.

Comment: @SSMA I do not understand what you mean by `SPi`. I believe you are using notations that are specific only for a given article. Maybe provide a link to the source you are reading?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev SPi is the length of the longest prefix which is also a suffix. P is the pattern and T is the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single answer for all cases.

Still you can give an upper bound on the number of comparisons and it is found if all symbols in `P` are the same. Try and compute that.

If this is not enough try using this property: KMP will compare `T[k]` against P[SP<sub>i</sub>] and then against P[SP<sub>SP<sub>i</sub>+1</sub>] and so on until one of two options happens:

- The given letter matches `T[k]`
- The value of the given SP is 0

The two above may happen in many different ways depending on P and T and so it is impossible to give a closed formula.

Comment: This was certainly not the answer i was looking for.
I talked to my teacher but he wants us to think more on it. He gave a hint that somehow the length of pattern is involved.

Comment: @SSMA actually the length of the pattern is involved in the worst case estimate I propose in the first part of my answer.

Comment: at last my teacher told us the solution. And your answer was perfect. Thanks a lot!